# Row based security with application users strategy

Tags: postgresql

Hi I have a question regarding the approach I can take regarding limiting the data an application user has access to potentially using row level security in PostgreSQL 12.

In my scenario I have a set of report tables where each table has a column called site_id. All the rows that have the same site_id are common to each other.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE public.devices (
page_views int8 NOT NULL,
agent_id int4 NOT NULL,
site_id int4 NOT NULL,
date_visit date NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT devices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (site_id, date_visit, agent_id))
```

There is a separate set of tables having to do with application users. Application users have a relationship to a set of site_ids.

So, user 'bob' is related to site_id (17, 18, 400, 122). Therefore when 'bob' logs into the
web report tool and executes a query bob should only see rows that have 17, 18, 400 and 122 as their site_id. Is this something that can be implemented using PostgreSQL row level security and can it be implemented without having to create a second user in PostgreSQL representing application user 'bob'? I limit what 'bob' sees now via the interface I just want to know if it can be implemented using row level security instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is some way in SQL to determine who the current user is.

So you need some state in the database.

You could use a placeholder parameter:

```
SET application.user = 'bob';
```

and test with

```
current_setting('application.user')
```

or you could use a temporary table with a single entry.

Answer (score 1):

Laurenz, Thanks for setting me on the right path. This is what I have decided to do for now:

```
create policy test_policy on devices
using (site_id in ((select unnest (string_to_array(current_setting('application.siteids'), ',')::int[]))));

set application.siteids = '244,681';
select * from devices;
```

Comment: You can remove the unnest and simplify your condition to: `site_id = any (string_to_array(current_setting('application.siteids'), ',')::int[])`